# How come `readResolve` is an instance method if it returns the calling object?

Tags: java, singleton, deserialization

I know readResolve is the hook that deals with creation/returning the deserialized object. It can be used while ensuring the Singleton class has only one object even after multiple deserializations. But the method is instance method and defined in the class whose object is being deserialized. So how come the method gets called in first place? Is there any other functionality involved?

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood. (De)Serialization creates an object from bytes, then asks this object whether it wants to get replaced.

```
private Object readResolve() {
    return this;
}
```

is a perfectly fine way to implement this method. It's just pointless because it means "don't replace me". The same thing happens when this method is not present.

---

You can make that visible when you deserialize the following

```
class Elvis implements Serializable {
    { System.out.println("Initializer of " + this); }
    private Elvis() { System.out.println("Constructor of " + this); }

    static final Elvis THE_ELVIS = new Elvis();

    private Object readResolve() {
        System.out.println("readResolve of " + this);
        new Exception("This is how we get called:").printStackTrace();
        return THE_ELVIS; // we're not the real one and don't want to be
                          // the result of deserialization. Replace with
                          // proper instance.
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/kd2PdS

Answer (score 0):

The object begin deserialized is deserialized, and then its `readResolve()` method is called if present to determine what is actually returned by `readObject()`. It can be used as you say to substitute a singleton instance of the same class, or it can be used to return an instance of a completely different class., for example when the corresponding `writeObjext()` method has substituted a proxy object to be serialized.